# Can't use some functions in C#!

Tags: c#, silverlight, function, windows-phone-7, reference

I can't seem to get access to some C# functions even though I have included the proper files/references! I can't seem to get access to System.Net.Dns or System.Net.WebRequest.GetRequestStream! Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: What files/references have you included that you think are the correct ones?  How did you include them?

Comment: Are you including the System.Net name space?  You may have to post some code so others could try part of what you have.

Comment: In the absence of any details, I'm going to guess that you're using Silverlight and answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're using Silverlight, where those aren't available.

If you go to the MSDN page for [`WebRequest.GetRequestStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.getrequeststream.aspx) or [`System.Net.Dns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.aspx), you'll see a link near the top that says "Other Versions". If you click on it, you'll see that it lists a number of things like ".NET Framework 4". If the platform you're using isn't listed, you can't use the API. For example, Silverlight isn't mentioned for those APIs, so they're not available in Silverlight.

Comment: Oh crap you're right. Yeah I'm using Win7 Phone. How would I get my host name in this case?

Comment: @Reggie: Ask a question like "How do I get my host name in WP7?"

Answer (score 1):

[This blog entry](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2011/03/17/HttpWebRequestGetResponseAndGetRequestStreamInWindowsPhone7.aspx) might also be of interest/use for the first one.